# Is it possible to change the order of an ion-row?

Tags: html, ionic3, responsive, ion-grid

I'm implementing a responsive grid, like the one you can see in the image:

[image]

I know it is possible to change the order of the columns in Ionic, but is it possible to do the same with rows?

For example, currently, the order of the rows is red, yellow and green. **I would like it to be green, red and yellow for large screens.** Is that possible? Something like [`offset-*` or `push-*` and `pull-*`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/grid/Grid/#reordering) but for rows.

Or would you try to find a better approach to this? Maybe another structure using columns, which we know can be ordered.

For now, this is the code I have:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            Things inside
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            Things inside
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

        <!-- I want this row to be the first on large screens -->
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            Things inside
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col col-12>
        Things inside
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Comment: I know you can use the CSS property `order` when inside of a flex parent on the web. I would give this a shot and see what happens: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/reorder-group

Comment: Thanks for the Mozilla resource (hope IE, which I need to support, doesn't complaint too much about `flex-direction`). About the Ionic one, I think it is for Ionic 4, isn't it? Not sure if that would work on Ionic 3.

Answer (score 0):

- Move the data inside each row to a javascript object and change the UI to implement a forEach to load all the data

```
class ColData: any;
class RowData: ColData[];
class GridData: RowData[];
```

- when screen size is your desired

```
window.attachEvent('onresize', function(event) {
  // trigger here
});
```

change the order of the object

PS: you may have to use changedetector